# Setting up the movesense development environment with vagrant

Tags: movesense

I tried to set up the development environment with vagrant by following this guide, "Automated setup on all operating systems using Vagrant" at https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/523308c2b380fcde46d51af9af2f9ed17907ab55/README.md

However, I am not able to download a remote file. Here is the error output:

```
~/symbio/suunto-movesense-device-lib-c96b25358d86$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'ubuntu/artful64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'ubuntu/artful64'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/artful64
==> default: Adding box 'ubuntu/artful64' (v20180718.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/artful64/versions/20180718.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
    default: Download redirected to host: cloud-images.ubuntu.com
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

How I can fix this problem?

Using Vagrant 2.2.3 and Debian 9.7

Answer (score 0):

this is probably caused by the Debian artfull64 going out of support and the repo/image taken down from Ubuntu servers.

Try updating to a version of Ubuntu that is newer (Xenial or Bionic) to get LTS and not having the build break again too soon.

To upgrade edit the config.vm.box line in the Vagrant file:

```
config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/xenial64'
```

Possible candidates for the box can be found in the vagrant documentation
https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search

I had a similar issue with it and got the Movesense guys to update to artful from zesty I also warned them that artful would go out of support in July 2018 and that they should use LTS version of Ubuntu.

The main problem was to get a version that hat the "gcc-arm-embedded" package in its repo and at the time I had the issue it was not in bionic/xenial at that time but it should be by now.